# Android - unregister BroadcastReceiver from class?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How to unregister a receiver from class? So far I got this code.. As i press the button for the first time, everything works, but when I press it again app crashes with error: **..Error receiving broadcast Intent...** and the error is not handled. For my understanding I cannot register the receiver twice, but how to overcome this?

```
public class ApplianceButtonToggleOnClickListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
LinearLayoutWithImage mHardwareCell;
Activity mActivity;
    public ApplianceButtonToggleOnClickListener(
            LinearLayoutWithImage mHardwareCell, Activity mActivity) {
        this.mHardwareCell = mHardwareCell;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
     ...

          mActivity.startService(intentMyIntentService);
          ApplianceStateChangeSuccessReceiver successReceiver = new  ApplianceStateChangeSuccessReceiver(mActivity,mHardwareCell);
          IntentFilter intentHardwareSyncFilter = new IntentFilter(UpdateHardwareStateService.ACTION_UpdateHardwareStateService);
      intentHardwareSyncFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);    


      try {
          mActivity.registerReceiver(successReceiver, intentHardwareSyncFilter);} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.d ("APPLIANCE_BUTTON_TOGGLE_ON_CLICK", "ApplianceButtonToggleOnClick: error " +e);
          }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a global reference to your receiver, and register/unregister it in your `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods, respectively.  Also, if you're getting an "error receiving broadcast intent", it's likely that your receiver is receiving a broadcast, and you are handling it incorrectly -- however, without seeing the stack trace/your receiver code that's mainly just a guess.  Here's a quick example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

BroadcastReceiver yourReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        yourReceiver = new YourImplementation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(yourReceiver, new IntentFilter(YOURACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Register and unregister receiver in onResume() and onPause().

```
@Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(yourReceiver, new IntentFilter(YOURACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
    }
```

Chk this:https://developers.geoloqi.com/android/handling-events